Match all files in directory and index files from first level children
I have a list of URIs and one parameter $path.
I want to match URIs based on that $path. I want to get all files in $path + all index files from subdirectories but ONLY for the first child. So I don't wanna get all index files from all subdirectories.
Example: $path = /root
/root/index.shtml           - MATCH ME (because file is in $path)
/root/root_one.shtml        - MATCH ME (because file is in $path)
/root/one/index.shtml       - MATCH ME (because im an index-child)
/root/two/index.shtml       - MATCH ME (because im an index-child)
/root/two/test.shtml        - DONT MATCH ME
/root/two/three/index.shtml - DONT MATCH ME
/root/2024/index.shtml      - MATCH ME (because im an index-child)
/root/2024/one.shtml        - DONT MATCH ME

At least based on my knowledge, I think I have to use two regex to match everything.
Match all files within directory: \/root\/(\w+)\.shtml
Match all index.shtml on first childs: \/root\/(\w+)\/{1}index\.shtml
Is there a way to match both in one regex?
Update: I think just when updating, i found a solution: \/root\/(\w+)(\/{1}index\.shtml|\.shtml)

In general you can use pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|... to match multple things in one regex.

You can avoid using backslash for slash characters and use another separator, here I use pipe |: m|/root/(\w+)(/{1}index\.shtml|\.shtml)|

Dupe question is entirely different from the stated problem statement here.

You may use a single regex like this to match all the cases:
^\/root\/[^\/]+(?:\/index\.shtml)?$

RegEx Demo
RegEx Demo:

^: Start
\/root\/: Match /root/
[^\/]+: Match 1+ of any character that is not /
(?:\/index\.shtml)?: Match /index.shtml optionally
$: End


Since this is used for a web based application, would you rather use [^\/] or (\w+) to match all filenames?

Eventho i found a solution myself, I will accept this as answer as appreciation for helping.

You can also use ^\/root\/[\w.-]+(?:\/index\.shtml)?$

The alternative solution, ^\/root\/[\w.-]+(?:\/index\.shtml)?$ is equally good.

Instead of a regex, you can specify your rules. Most people reach for the regex because they don't realize that core Perl already has tools (File::Spec) to break apart a path. Once you have the components, you can check them in the same way that you specify what you are looking for:
use v5.10;
use experimental qw(signatures);

use File::Spec;

while( <DATA> ) {
    my( $path ) = split;
    say $path if matches($path, 'root', 'index.shtml');
    }

sub matches ($path, $target_dir, $target_file) {
    my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir($path);
    shift @dirs; # no volumes here

       if( $dirs[0] ne $target_dir ) { 0 }
    elsif( @dirs == 2 ) { 1 }
    elsif( @dirs == 3 and $dirs[-1] eq $target_file ) { 1 }
    else { 0 }
    }

__END__
/root/index.shtml           - MATCH ME (because file is in $path)
/root/root_one.shtml        - MATCH ME (because file is in $path)
/root/one/index.shtml       - MATCH ME (because im an index-child)
/root/two/index.shtml       - MATCH ME (because im an index-child)
/root/two/test.shtml        - DONT MATCH ME
/root/two/three/index.shtml - DONT MATCH ME
/root/2024/index.shtml      - MATCH ME (because im an index-child)
/root/2024/one.shtml        - DONT MATCH ME

If you don't like the if stuff, you can make it a logical expression:
sub matches ($path, $target_dir, $target_file) {
    my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir($path);
    shift @dirs; # no volumes here

    ($dirs[0] eq $target_dir) && (
         @dirs == 2
         ||
        (@dirs == 3 and $dirs[-1] eq $target_file)
        )
    }

Typically I find that people will want to reuse the same logical but with different directories and target files (and maybe even different depths. At that point the regex solution gets out of hand.
